# Is there a way to upload files from Windows Gadget?

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, windows-desktop-gadgets

From `System.Shell.itemFromFileDrop` I get `System.Shell.Item` object `item`. I've tried this:

```
var oStream = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");
oStream.Type = 1;
oStream.Open();

oStream.LoadFromFile(item.path);
content = oStream.Read();

var thisObj = this;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "http://myUrl.com//");
xhr.send(content);    //NOT WORKING

oStream.Close();
oStream = null;
```

but I really don't know what to pass in the `xhr.send` function.

The serverside PHP code is as simple as it could be:

```
if (file_exists($_FILES["file"]["name"]))
{
    echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
}
else
{
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    header("{$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']} 200 OK");
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    echo "http://myUrl.com/" .$_FILES["file"]["name"];
}
```

any ideas what am I doing wrong ? Or any ideas about how to upload files from windows gadget at all?

Comment: Not to ask stupid questions, but can you upload straight text to the server? What error are you getting? You may need to set a new header for uploading what you are, or set the content-type on the xhr to binary or something?